# Sub-tasks and Greenhoper

Tags: jira, jira-plugin, jira-agile

Is it possible to see the sub-tasks in the Greenhopper plan screen of the agile page ?
As it is now, we can only see the cases and not the children sub-tasks (sub-cases)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not possiblity to see the sub-task in the sprint or backlog in Greenhoper Version: 6.1.3.1

Answer (score 0):

The sub tasks are shown in the 'sub tasks' section of the detail view on the right when you click in the issue. Since sub tasks are not freestanding items of work they're not shown directly in the backlog.

Thanks,
Shaun

Comment: Yes but it seems impossible to have them in the sprint list and therefore use the subtasks filter. We have a case with subtasks assigned to different users.

Comment: @gpasse I've also had simillar problems. You should contact the [Atlassian Support Team](http://support.atlassian.com/) for more info. They should be able to solve your problem or if not include it as a feature in the a future release of Greenhopper. Sadly there are some aspects of GreenHopper that in my opinion look a bit overlooked.

Comment: @BorislavSabev I add the feeling this was a missing feature too. I will contact them. Hopefully get this new feature up. Because as it is now we calculate by hand.